# svg object pattern, how to multiply it

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So I have a svg pattern which has 9 dots (3x3) inside with a transparent background. I have brought this in my html as an object, because I also have to change the color of the dots, I dont think I can do it with just CSS.

Now I need to repeat this object so I would have fullscreen worth of dots? How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, it is possible to use CSS to change dots color. For example:

```
<object id="object" type="image/svg+xml" data="/paht/to/mysvg.svg"></object>

var a = document.getElementById("object");
        var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
        var styleElement = svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "style");
        styleElement.textContent = "* { fill: #000 }";
        svgDoc.documentElement.appendChild(styleElement);
```

And you can access to each childs(`dots`) in your root(`svgDoc.documentElement`) and manupulate it as you want, for example to multiply dots and so on via `svgDoc.documentElement.childNodes`.

Comment: I'm a big noob, so unfortunately I don't know what I need more besides the svgDoc.documentElement.childNodes

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the SVG `use` tag:

```
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#svg-icon" />
</svg>

<svg id="defs" style="display:none">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 13 13">
      <path d="M2,2 L11.1923882,11.1923882"></path>
      <path d="M11.1923882,2 L2,11.1923882"></path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

This example draws you an 'X'. I can style it with CSS by targeting the `<svg>`:

```
.icon {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: red;
}
```

Props to [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/), where I originally picked this up.